# Resume composer project installation

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.4

I have created 
laravel project through `composer --create-project`, but during installation my internet connection broken.
I wonder if there is a way to resume the installation without deleting my project folder and start process again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the installation fail you cannot resume the installation without remove vendors directory completely.

Will be a good idea write the composer.lock for each package installed successfully so you can resume the installation later.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/378

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project):

> You can use Composer to create new projects from an existing package. This is the equivalent of doing a git clone/svn checkout followed by a "composer install" of the vendors.

You can execute `composer install` and it will install the dependencies that aren't already installed.